# Not able to make as alias or xtype of data field

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic, xtype

I have defined like

```
Ext.define('Abc.view.component.model.RegModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.field.String',
    alias: 'regionModel',
    name: 'REGION',
});

 Ext.define('Abc.view.report.trig.Model', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        alias: 'TRIG',
        fields: [
            { xtype:'regionModel'}
        ]
    });
```

xtype i have defined and used does not work. How do i create such thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
alias: 'data.field.regionModel'
```

Instead of:

```
alias: 'regionModel'
```

And in the `Model` use `type` instead of `xtype`.

(`xtype` is used for `widget` aliases only)

Answer (score 2):

Pointing you to the right place in sencha docs.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0-classic/Ext.data.field.Field.html#ext-data-field-field_custom-types